# How to create new column with all the values from another column starting from 2nd row in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create new column which should contain values from another column starting from second. This means that for the new column, the last value will be Nan.

Dataset example.

```
A   B   C 

10  20  30 
40  50  60
70  80  90
100 110 120
```

New column needed as:

```
A  B    C   D

10 20   30  50
40 50   60  80
70 80   90  110
110 110 120 Nan
```

The column D needs values to be extracted from column B starting from 2nd row.

I tried the code as:

```
df['D'] = [df['B'][i] for i in range(0, len(df))]
```

This obviously gives the same as B, I am unable to change the rows from 1:len(df)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`shift(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
>>> df['D'] = df['B'].shift(-1)
```

---

```
     A    B    C      D
0   10   20   30   50.0
1   40   50   60   80.0
2   70   80   90  110.0
3  100  110  120    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['D'] = df['B'].shift(-1)
```

output:

```
     A    B    C      D
0   10   20   30   50.0
1   40   50   60   80.0
2   70   80   90  110.0
3  100  110  120    NaN
```